# A few detection and correction questions

Tags: coding-theory

I need a bit of help with error detection and correction.

We have:

```
 C = {01010101, 10101010, 00000000, 11111111}
```

I need to:

```
1) compute d(C)  = min ({Hd(v,w) / v, w belongs to C});
2) find an error that can’t be detected where Hw(v) <= (d(c)-1)/3;
3) find an error that can be detected but not corrected;
```

PS. Is not a homework, is just one basics subjects from an old exam.

It would help me a lot a few solving hints. What I actually need, is to understand how to do them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You see that $C$ is a vector space, so $d(C)$ is just the minimum Hamming distance from zero of a non-zero vector in $C$, hence $4$.
2. Any error that takes an element of $C$ to another element of $C$, for instance when $01010101$ is sent, and $00000000$ is received.
3. Suppose you receive $v = 11110000$. This has distance $4$ from all the elements of $C$, so it could come via $4$ bit-errors from any of them. You see there are errors because $v \notin C$.

Comment: Great Andreas! Thank you! I still have a few questions:  Why 4? 4 is the correct answer, I saw it on the paper, but why 4? Please have a look on the attached picture http://i61.tinypic.com/nb2dk9.jpg. Can you explain me why what I noted with a is 8 and b,c,d,e is 4? And why those choises? I mean, why don't first zero to first 1?

Comment: The Hamming distance from zero of a binary vector $v$ is simply the number of $1$'s in it. Also, you should have been taught that $Hd(a,b) = Hd(a-b,0)$, where of course over the field with two elements $a-b = a + b$. See if you can proceed from here.

Comment: The thing that don't make sense for me is how I chose those distances. According with the definition, I should take the distance from 0 to first non-zero element. Why in the the solution from my photo the first 0 is last one?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following you. Which definition? The "first non-zero element" of what? What do you mean by "the first $0$ is last one"?

Comment: From 01010101. Why did they start from last 0 and not from first or second? You can see here http://i61.tinypic.com/nb2dk9.jpg better what I want to say.